# Scoping in recursive function leading to unexpected results

Tags: programming, recursion

I'm trying to implement [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker line simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) in *Mathematica*, and I'm running into an issue with recursion. My implementation of the algorithm is below:

```
RDP[points_, ϵ_] := (
  Print[points];
  start := points[[1]];
  end := points[[-1]];
  vec := Normalize[end - start];
  dist[p_] := (
    t := Dot[(p - start), vec];
    loc := start + t*vec;
    Norm[loc - p]
    );
  distances := Map[dist, points];
  maxdist := Max[distances];
  maxelem := FirstPosition[distances, maxdist][[1]];
  res := If[maxdist < ϵ,
    {start, end},
    p0 := points[[1 ;; maxelem]];
    p1 := points[[maxelem ;;]];
    fst := RDP[p0, ϵ];
     Print["Run with p1 = ", p1];
    snd := RDP[p1, ϵ];
    Join[fst, snd];
    ];
  Print["result ", res];
  res
  )
line := {{0, -1}, {5, 5}, {5, 16}, {11, 23}}
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 25}, RDP[line, 1]]
```

I'm getting a very strange result. A snippet of the output:

> ```
> {{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16},{11,23}}    
> Run with p1 = {{5,16},{11,23}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16}}    
> Run with p1 = {{5,5},{5,16}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> result {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16}}    
> Run with p1 = {{5,5},{5,16}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> result {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16}}    
> Run with p1 = {{5,5},{5,16}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> result {{0,-1},{5,5}}    
> {{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16}}    
> Run with p1 = {{5,5},{5,16}}
> ```

It looks like `p0` and `p1` are set correctly after the split, and I can verify that the recursive call succeeds when it's called on `p0`. However, on the second recursive call, the value passed into the function is not the value that the function actually runs on; you can see that, when p1 is set to `{{5,16},{11,23}}`, `RDP[p1, ϵ]` actually runs with points set to `{{0,-1},{5,5},{5,16}}`.

I'm not the most experienced *Mathematica* user, and this is my first time implementing this sort of recursive function, so I might be missing something pretty simple. Any help or pointers welcome!

Comment: Why don't you localize the variables inside the function? Look up `Module`, and also the difference betweeen `=` and `:=` (Set vs SetDelayed).

Comment: You'll have to localize variables. Using globals in a recursive function just isn't going to work.